# prevent same name in field kode barang

Tags: jquery

Hello guys i have add auto row please check [here](http://codepen.io/sidaurukfreddy/pen/XNroJW) my question how prevent input type text **kode barang** when has same value, there is no double value kode barang

This is my view table

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                        <th width="15%">Kode Barang</th>
                        <th width="38%">Nama Barang</th>
                        <th width="15%">Harga</th>
                        <th width="15%">Jumlah</th>
                        <th width="15%">Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="kode_barang" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="price[]"  readonly id="price_1" name="price[]" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" name="quantity[]" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
                                                   </td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="total[]" readonly id="total_1" name="total[]" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
  </div>


    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Add More</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: prevent it from what?

Comment: prevent in that table has same value kode barang, will update question

Comment: prevent to do what ?

Comment: @madalinivascu to make sure user will not input type double kode barang,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent the same value on new input, use this code I've just changed for you:

```
    var i=$('table tr').length;
    var myArr = [];
    $(".addmore").on('click',function(){
      var selection = '#itemNo_' + (i - 1);
      var inputValue = $(selection).val();
      var sameValue = false;
      $.each(myArr , function(index, value){
         if (value == inputValue) {
             alert('you entered the same value => ' + inputValue);
             sameValue = true;
             return false;
           }
      });
      if (sameValue == true) {
        return;
      }
      else {
         myArr.push(inputValue);  
      }
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="kode_barang" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" readonly id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]"  id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" readonly id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);
        i++;
    });
```

Comment: your script has bugs, please check it when you leave input type empty and click add button it's show alert